# Date adding error, Case Else seems to doesn't work at all

Tags: vba

```
Function Zad3(x As String, y As Date)
    Dim z As String, c As Integer
    z = Right(x, 1)
    c = Left(Right(x, 2), 1)
    Select Case z
        Case Is = "M"
            Zad3 = DateAdd("m", c, y)
        Case Is = "R"
            Zad3 = DateAdd("yyyy", c, y)
        Case Is = "L"
            Zad3 = DateAdd("yyyy", c, y)
        Case Else
            Zad3 = "nieznana"
    End Select

End Function
```

[image]

So "z" is "L", "M" or "R", where "L","R" = year and "M" = month. I need to add to the date 3L, so 3 years, it works. I have a problem where there's sth else e.g. "?".It should show "nieznane" because of the Else Case, but it doesn't. Idk how to solve it, any ideas?

Comment: `c = Left(Right(x, 2), 1)` - you can't take the rightmost 2 characters of a 1 character string.

Comment: @SJR beat me to it :) Check `len(x)` will allow

Comment: Ignore the previous comments as they have misread your post. Nowhere do you say that X is a one character string.  I am not an regular Excel user so will defer to those more knowledgeable than myself, but  you may need to change the format of the target cell from Date to General for the string to show as "niezname"

Comment: You should also be using option explicit at the start of your module and also specifying they type of variable that will be returned from you function.  At the moment you are using an implicit variant.  "niezname" is not a variant date

Comment: @freeflow, those who made first two comments have both read the question and looked at the images carefully. While it seems you have not.

Comment: @HTH I'm always willing to correct my mistakes.  I can only see x defined in the parameter list.  Additionally, neither the Left nor Right methods give an error if provided with parameters that are outside the string length.  Consequently, if column 3 (which is where I am assuming that x comes from) is  ? or ""  or empty then z will be "" and should trigger  the else clause. That's why I conclude the error is outside the function provided and may be due to a type mismatch in a calculation or assignment we have not been shown.

Comment: @freeflow, you're right for the `Right()` part, since `Right("?", 2)` would not error and yeald "?". But you're wrong with _" error is outside the function"_, since it's caused by that very statement `c = Left(Right(x, 2), 1)` being `Dim c As Integer`. So I was correspondingly wrong and right...

Answer (score 0):

the problem lies in:

```
c = Left(Right(x, 2), 1)
```

which would error out for`x` ="?", since:

- Left(Right(x, 2), 1) would yeald "?"
- `c` is declared as `Integer`

and VBA interpreter couldn't convert "?" to any integer value for `c`

so, you should move that statement inside their proper, and safe, cases

```
Function Zad3 (x As String, y As Date)
    Dim z As String, c As Integer
    z = Right(x, 1)
    Select Case z
        Case Is = "M"
            c = Left(Right(x, 2), 1)
            Zad3 = DateAdd("m", c, y)
        Case Is = "R"
            c = Left(Right(x, 2), 1)
            Zad3 = DateAdd("yyyy", c, y)
        Case Is = "L"
            c = Left(Right(x, 2), 1)
            Zad3 = DateAdd("yyyy", c, y)
        Case Else
            Zad3 = "nieznana"
    End Select

End Function
```

a short version of which, could be

```
Public Function Zad3(x As String, y As Date)
    Dim z As String

    z = Right(x, 1)
    Select Case z
        Case "M", "R", "L"
            Zad3 = DateAdd(Switch(z = "M", "m", z = "R", "yyyy", z = "L", "yyyy"), Left(x, Len(x) - 1), y)

        Case Else
            Zad3 = "nieznana"
    End Select
End Function
```

where I used VBA `Switch()` function to *collapse* what would be another `Select Case` block

Answer (score -1):

### Conditional Date Modification

```
Option Explicit

Function Zad3(SourceString As String, SourceDate As Date) As Variant

    ' Function restriction: only 1 to 9 months or years can be added.

    Dim strT As String  ' Type String
    Dim strN As String  ' Number String
    Dim lngN As Long    ' Number Number

    ' Check if there is at least two characters in SourceString.
    If Len(SourceString) < 2 Then GoTo Nieznana

    ' Calculate Type String (right-most character).
    strT = Right(SourceString, 1)
    ' Calculate Number String (first (left) of the two right-most characters).
    strN = Left(Right(SourceString, 2), 1)

    ' Check if Number String can be converted to a number.
    If Not IsNumeric(strN) Then GoTo Nieznana

    ' Convert Number String to Number Number.
    lngN = CLng(strN)

    ' It there was no IsNumeric:
'    On Error Resume Next
'        lngC = CLng(strN)
'        If Err.Number > 0 Then GoTo Nieznana
'    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Calculate resulting date (Zad3).
    Select Case strT
        Case Is = "M": Zad3 = DateAdd("m", lngN, SourceDate)
        Case Is = "R", "L": Zad3 = DateAdd("yyyy", lngN, SourceDate)
        Case Else: GoTo Nieznana
    End Select

Exit Function

Nieznana:
    ' 1. Source String has less than two characters.
    ' 2. Number String can not be converted to a number.
    ' 3. Type String is not "M", "R" or "L".
    Zad3 = "nieznana"

End Function
```